# append javascript variable after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a javascript variable to a page after the page loads?  I have a PHP ajax function that I need to return a javascript variable.  I've tried echoing the variable between script tags and it's not working.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you provide more information? Perhaps some code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this, is to create a php document that just echos out the variable, with no markup, and not even any trailing linebreaks.

```
<?php echo($var); ?>
```

Then ajax that page, and in the success clause of the ajax call, just do;

```
success: function(result) { myGlobalJavascriptVariable = result; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the variable name at page load, you could do it this way:

### Javascript:

```
$.ajax({url:'/releventScript.php',
       data: RelevantData,
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data){
           window[data.varName]=data.varValue;
       }
      });
```

### PHP Script

```
$response=array('varName'=>'Foo',
                'varValue'=>'Bar');
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

This will allow you to dynamically create variables in the global namespace.